# GCP bill calls to storage buckets from the same zone?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-billing

GCP bill requests to storage objects in the same zone? I didn't find this in the documentation.

Example: if I will use GS as Key/Value storage, internally inside of one zone, I will pay only for storage or for requests too?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Google Cloud Storage Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#pricing), you are charged both for the [data you store](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#storage-pricing) and [inbound/outbound operations (requests)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing). This means that you will be charged an amount of $ per month based on the [storage class](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes) and [bucket location](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/locations) and any operations that are performed within Google Cloud Storage. Google Cloud Platform has a [Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/) to help you calculate the pricing you would incur using Google Cloud Platform products. I recommend you to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage (GCS) charges on a per-operation rate, regardless of whether you're making calls from the same region. Per-operation costs vary based on storage class and what type of call, but it's around 5-10 cents per 10,000 operations.

Google Cloud Storage separately charges you for data egress, and egress is mostly free within a region, but the operations themselves still have their cost.

If your goal is to frequently access/mutate a large key/value table with relatively small values, Cloud Bigtable is likely to be a cheaper and faster option. If your goal is to store comparatively large objects, GCS is likely to be a better choice. If you have a good idea of what sort of operations you're likely going to use, I  highly suggest using the pricing calculator to estimate your costs.